# MPICH communication failed

Tags: c++, linux, communication, mpich

I have a simple MPICH program in which processes send & receive messages from each other in a Ring order.
I've setup to 2 identical virtual machine, and made sure network is working fine. I've tested a simple MPICH program both machines and it works fine.
The problem arises when I try to communicate between processes on different machines like the above program. I'm getting the following error:

> Fatal error in MPI_Send: A process has failed, error stack:
>   MPI_Send(171)...............: MPI_Send(buf=0xbfed8c08, count=1, MPI_INT, dest=1,
>   tag=1, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
>   MPID_nem_tcp_connpoll(1826): Communication error with rank 1: Connection refused

- SSH is passwordless & works fine on both sides.
- `/etc/hosts` is configured properly.
- Firewall is disabled on both machines.
- Configured NFS Client/Server and shared a directory between them. (According to [this](http://webappl.blogspot.com/2011/05/setting-up-mpich2-cluster-with-ubuntu.html))
- Tried both MPICH & OpenMPI with Hydra

Comment: What cluster application are you using? I meant how you submitting job to multiple node?

Comment: @Satish I'm not sure I understood your question correctly but I'm using `mpiexec -f hosts -n 4 ./myapp` which I think uses shh under the hood.

Comment: Make sure you have passwordless ssh (public/private key)

Comment: I'm not very good with linux, How do I make ssh passwordless?

Comment: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152

Comment: More help http://rcsg-gsir.imsb-dsgi.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/documents/internet/node31.html

Comment: @Satish Made ssh password-less on both sides. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Disable firewall or SELinux if it running..

Comment: Are you using Hydar or some short of cluster manger application see: http://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Using_the_Hydra_Process_Manager

Comment: Here is your solution: http://webappl.blogspot.com/2011/05/setting-up-mpich2-cluster-with-ubuntu.html

Comment: @Satish firewall is disabled, I believe Hydra is used in my version of MPICH2 automatically. (looking at the link now)

Comment: Configured NFS, but still getting the same error. To make sure hydra is in use, I run programs in mpiexec.hydra instead of mpiexec.

Comment: Did you try to run debug mode? It seem problem is either network or hydra setup. Make sure you are able to ssh from both machine without  ppassword.

Comment: @Satish Passwordless SSH works fine from both sides and both machines can ping eachother. Although I'm suspicious about hydra. I tried installng it using `sudo apt-get install hydra` but problem remained still. As said before I even tried `mpiexec.hydra` to make sure hydra is in use. How do I run MPI programs in debug mode? any links?

Comment: Check out my answer! below it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here what i did, And it works!

Installed following package using source code (tarball)

```
hydra 
openmpi
```

Created hosts file (both node)

```
# cat /home/spatel/mpi/hydra/hosts
node1
node2
```

Set variable in .bashrc on (both node)

```
echo HYDRA_HOST_FILE=/home/spatel/mpi/hydra/hosts >> ~/.bashrc
```

Use HelloWorld MPI program to run on single node.

```
node1# /home/spatel/mpi/hydra/bin/mpiexec -np 1 /home/spatel/mpi/mpi_hello_world
Hello world from processor node1.example.com, rank 0 out of 1 processors
```

Run on multiple node using `-machinefile` option `-np` is number of processor

```
node1# /home/spatel/mpi/hydra/bin/mpiexec -np 4 -machinefile /home/spatel/mpi/hydra/hosts /home/spatel/mpi/mpi_hello_world
Hello world from processor node1.example.com, rank 0 out of 1 processors
Hello world from processor node2.example.com, rank 0 out of 1 processors
Hello world from processor node1.example.com, rank 0 out of 1 processors
Hello world from processor node2.example.com, rank 0 out of 1 processors
```

Comment: I download openmpi and compiled it from source. Same about hydra. Then used `mpiexec.hydra -f hosts -n 2 ./a.out` to run the program. I got the same error :( Thanks for your help though. You've already done too much. I'm guessing there may be problems with VMWare networking.

Comment: If you able to do ssh then I don't think it's a network issue could be your host windows firewall if you have bridge networking try NAT

Comment: Tried NAT, also tried turning off my Windows AntiVirus program. Still fails.