# MPICH/SLURM assign host rank

Tags: c, mpi, mpich, slurm

I'm using MPICH with SLURM and am trying to assign a rank to a specific node (due to hardware differences, I want a specific node to always be rank 0). MPICH is using the Hydra Process Manager. Checking the documentation I should be able to have a rank file (or machine file, not sure the difference) with a list of hosts that get assigned in round robin.

Here is an example program I'm using for testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char hostname[256];
    int rank;
    int size;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    gethostname(hostname,255);

    printf("I am rank: %d on host %s\n", rank, hostname);

    if (rank == 0) {
        for (int x = 1; x < size; x++) {
            int recv;
            MPI_Recv(&recv, 1, MPI_INT, x, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            printf("host %s : rank %d received %d\n", hostname, rank, recv);
        }
    } else {
        printf("host %s : rank %d is sending a message\n", hostname, rank);
        MPI_Send(&rank, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

My rank file contents is as follows:

```
node02
node01
```

Because I want node02 to be assigned rank zero. I then run the following:

```
salloc -N2 -c 24 -p debug mpiexec -machinefile ./rankfile.txt ./mpi_test
```

This fails with the output and error:

```
I am rank: 0 on host node01
I am rank: 1 on host node02
host node02 : rank 1 is sending a message
Fatal error in MPI_Send: Unknown error class, error stack:
MPI_Send(174)..............: MPI_Send(buf=0x7fff9503155c, count=1, MPI_INT, dest=0, tag=0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPID_nem_tcp_connpoll(1835): Communication error with rank 0: Connection refused
```

Searching about this error has not been helpful and setting HYDRA_DEBUG does not provide additional info about the error. I am able to SSH between the two nodes fine, running without the -f (or -machinefile) flag and rankfile works fine, and swapping the order of hosts in the rankfile (equivalent to running without the rank file, effectively) runs fine. Strangely, printing out the rank and hostname info running with the rankfile still shows node01 to be rank zero... Another strange behavior is that changing the rankfile to:

```
node03
node01
```

Fails completely with SLURM saying "Requested node configuration not available" however, running with -N3 and using all three nodes works with no problem (node03 is a valid node in the debug pool).

Is this a configuration problem? Am I using the flags wrong or the wrong flags? It seems OpenMPI has better support for assigning ranks than MPICH, but setting up SLURM and MPICH wasn't trivial due to the cluster setup so I'm hesitant to start over with OpenMPI.

Comment: Read [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571203/mpich-communication-failed). 
So, I suggest to try that. You can find documentation on Open MPI installation from source [here](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=building#easy-build). You can also install it from a repository depending on your OS.

The installation is straightforward (Well, most of the time:-) ). Let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: This usually happens (also with Open MPI) when the nodes try to communicate over TCP/IP, but the network configuration does not allow it. A typical reason could be the network setup of each node. For example, there might be network interfaces on the different nodes that share the same IP subnet, but are not physically connected. On some Linux distributions (mainly those derived from RHEL) there is a virtual bridge interface brought up automatically at boot by `libvirt` (for use with KVM guests). The IP network address is set in the default config file and will be the same on all nodes.